# zend framework 2 model/adapter reusable

Tags: php, zend-framework2, zend-framework-modules

I have a model which is used by two modules. I don't want to duplicate the code for that model into each modules.

For example I have 2 modules. First takes the blog posts from model and print them for normal users, and the other one prints them for admin users but with a few more options (which are set in the view). I would have the same model in two places. And.. that's bad.

Just a piece of code:

```
<?php
namespace Blog\Model;
use Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter;
use Zend\Db\ResultSet\ResultSet;
use Zend\Db\TableGateway\AbstractTableGateway;
class BlogTable extends AbstractTableGateway
{
    protected $table = 'blog_posts';
    public function __construct(Adapter $adapter)
    {
        $this->adapter = $adapter;
        $this->initialize();
    }
    /**
     * Gets the blog post list
     *
     * @return array
     **/
    public function fetchAll()
    {
        //..
    }
}
```

So, how should I design this application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The biggest question might be why you separate the administrative side outside of the 'Blog-Scope'. An administrative Module should only be the front-end to gather all backend-options (if that makes any sense)

However to get back into your question: you can simply include those classes from model A into model B, like `use Blog\Model\BlogTable`

Ultimately though i see management of a module as a responsible of the Blog-Module itself, as hinted within the first paragraph.

Edit: One thing i forgot to mention. Ideally if you decide to go the dependant approach, your module should make the BlogTable accessible through a service. That way your ModuleAdmin only has to do something like `$serviceLocator->get('my-blog-table')` which is a much more clean approach.

Comment: I assume you're talking about the 4th paragraph, since 3rd would be related to the 1st ;) For this, User Jurian Sluimans has posted a great blog article http://juriansluiman.nl/en/article/120/using-zend-framework-service-managers-in-your-application

Comment: In that case see the answer of DrBeza

Comment: To be precise: Write a Model "Blog" that has ALL the actions, add, edit, delete, moderate, view, detailview, etc.. AFTER that, you start using Zend\Permission to make actions like add/edit/delete/moderate only available to allowed members/roles

Comment: @SinaMiandashti No clue what won't work, but DoctrineEntities are just another way of storing Model Data into a Database, there's no real difference and pretty much everything works so far for me ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this by having a base/shared module that provides various models, helpers etc.

But personally I would be looking to architect modules around functionality rather than user access levels.